# Add an unrecognised style to an element inline

Tags: jquery, css

I have some JavaScript code which turns all styles on an element into an inline style. The reason for this is so the code can be exported for email and hopefully not break when emailed around.

Whilst the code is held on the page I'm also trying to add some additional email specific styles, namely `mso-line-height-rule: exactly;` [because of a problem I'm having](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/forums/topic/7376/outlook-2013-cell-height-bug-solution/).

However, if I set this using `.css('mso-line-height-rule', 'exactly')` it doesn't do it. I can only assume this is because the browser doesn't recognise it as a valid CSS style. Any ideas?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrChris2013/HDQpW/) and example code:

```
<article>
    <div></div>
</article>
```

JS

```
$('div').css({
    // Works
    'background-color': 'red',

    // Doesn't work
    'mso-inline-height': 'exactly'
});

alert($('article').html());
```

Comment: As you noted, it's because `mso-line-height-rule` isn't a valid CSS attribute. It's the same reason why `.css('frapple', 'schmoo')` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $('div').css({
// Works
'background-color': 'red',

// Doesn't work
'mso-inline-height': 'exactly'
});
//Grab any styles that were set with the css method
var style = $('div').attr('style');
//Append the non-standard MS Word bunk
$('div').attr('style', style + 'mso-inline-height:exactly;');
alert($('article').html());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HDQpW/1/

It's bringing the sledgehammer, but it should do the trick.

Comment: Perfect! My sledgehammer hasn't seen too much use of late so I'm happy to dust it off for this occasion.

Answer (score 0):

Using the attribute `attr()` selector instead of the css one will solve your immediate problem.

```
$("div").attr("style", "background-color: red; mso-inline-height: exactly");
```